Use efibootmgr to create a PXE network boot entry
I would like to create EFI a PXE boot entry on machines after having freshly PXE-booted them into an automated Debian or Rocky Linux installer. The main reason why I would want to do that is that newly installed distros tend to create an EFI entry to boot on local disk and set it as the first boot option, but I want the network boot option to remain the first boot attempt at every subsequent post-install boot. I am also aware that I can preseed the debian installer to not generate any EFI entry.. but then I do miss the local disk entry which should be attempted after PXE boot failure (which is expected to happen when the machine is not scheduled for being redeployed). Also, this observation is only valid on Debian. Finally, the PXE boot option does not seem to always exist at the end of Debian/Rocky Linux install so I need to create one from scratch and equally well on Debian and Rocky.
I could not find a way to use efibootmgr to generate such an entry for me. man efibootmgr does mention the "-i " option, but I could not ever make it generate a working boot entry. Dell efibootmgr github tells about options -U and -H which do not exist in Debian or Rocky. Can you suggest any other way accessible from the Linux (Debian and Rocky) OS environment to create such an entry?
